# Spree routing Error in production with a custom domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, spree

I try to run Spree on my server with a custom domain.
Everytime I click on a product or I want to login, the server routes me to 127.0.0.1:3000 instead of the correct domain.

I have tried several solutions exspecially on stack overflow, but my problem persists.

For example I've tried to add the following lines in my application-controller (which works in development mode):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def default_url_options
    if Rails.env.production?
      {:host => "myproduction.com"}
    else  
      {}
    end
  end
end
```

And I've tried to add `Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host]= 'mydomainname.com'` in config/environments/production.rb and to add the custom domain in /etc/hosts for 127.0.0.1.

Any idea where is my fault?

If any code helps, I can post it. But the most configuration files are not changed.